# Does Windows Server 2012 R2 support hot-add CPUs?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard guest in a virtual environment. My hypervisor (Virtualbox) supports hot-adding and hot-removing vCPU's, but it also says [in the VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#cpuhotplug) that "So far this applies only to Linux and Windows Server 2008 x64 Data Center Edition." Microsoft forums, as always, are no help.

**Please Note:** This is NOT a Virtualbox capability question, but a question of Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition's capability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can find nothing from MS, but Virtualization blogs seem to agree -- Windows 2012 Standard, and Datacenter will allow hot-adding vCPUs.

[image]

[Source](http://www.running-system.com/some-basics-about-hot-addhot-plug/)

[image]

[Source](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/blogs/lowe/news/vsphere-51-hot-add-ram-and-cpu.html)

Comment: Ah, I see. You must be a better Googler than I... Thank you!